# What is the best way to store a file within an Android app?

Tags: android, encryption

I am writing an app for my final year project, so it's more so for proof of concept so it doesn't have to be the best app in the world.

It is like a file locker app that you can add and remove files from the app and when they are stored they will be encrypted. There will be a login of some sort for the user to enter and be verified on a DB.
I am still a novice in android so I still have a way to go, but I am getting there!

I was thinking when the file (which could be a doc, pdf, jpg, video file etc) is added to the app it would be stored in the internal storage (from what I have read it seems to be the best place to store app related content) and a record of the name and file type would be added to the DB and also the encrypted file name. So when the user looks at the app they will see a thumbnail of the pic and the file name, kinda like the My Files app shows up files within a folder.

My question is it best not to store the file directly into the DB but just use the DB as a reference with the file details, if so how could this be done?

Also I was thinking that an AES 128bit encryption method would be best suited for this. I have tried a couple of encryption examples but have only been able to do this with a txt file, when i tried it with a jpg the app just sat there and did nothing. It showed the encrypted and decrypted jpg but this was not viewable.

Would anyone be able to suggest a good way of encrypting any file type that would suit for my app?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Owen

Comment: Is [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) not helpful?

Comment: aye it is useful, sure thats why I asked here. I shall have more of a look into it. Still new at this and just feeling overwhelmed with all the stuff to do ;-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this properly, here are a few tips:

1. Don't store files in the database, unless you know in advance that they're going to be really titchy. Store them somewhere else, with a reference to them in the database.
2. The best place for them if they're smallish is internal storage in the app's private file space. But if you want to be able to store encrypted arbitrary data then you'll need to hit external storage.
3. Don't store the decryption key!
4. Ideally, you should find a way not to write the file anywhere when you decrypt it. That might not be possible, though, if you need to open it in another application afterwards. If you write the encrypted files to external storage, you should at the very least write the decrypted version to internal storage where there's some operating system protection against other apps reading it. If you write the decrypted file to external storage, anything will be able to get at it.
5. AES with a 128-bit key will do you fine.

Comment: Please don't down-vote an answer without giving an indication as to why you think it's defective.

Comment: cool on storing of files in the DB, from other thing I have read say the same thing! With storing of the encrypted file on the external storage and then decrypting on the internal, that would be just temporary and then it would be deleted after viewing? Well for proof of concept I would have to have a variety of files and sizes so I'd say the external one might have to be the default location for the encrypted files, cheers for the clarification on that!

Comment: on another point I'm guessing that I would use the normal gallery or txt viewer that is on the phone to view the decrypted file....within or outside the app? Can I call these viewers inside an activity or fragment? Sorry for all the questions ;-p

Comment: Yes, you'd want to delete the temporary file (or, better, overwrite and then delete) after viewing. For file types that you can handle natively within the app, you could avoid writing them to a file at all: for text, you could decrypt in memory, and then put the contents into a text viewer within your app, and similarly for an image. But you'd probably want to allow the option to open them with the registered app for those files too (which would have to involve writing them to a file).